# Template parameter to vector::constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to code a small C++ reimplementation of GSL integraton routines as a practice project to learn C++ metaprogramming. I have the following question.

I've define some type traits (to make the program to work both with double and floats)

```
template<typename T> class IntegrationWorkspaceTraits;

template<> class IntegrationWorkspaceTraits<double>
{
     public:
     typedef double ft; //float_type
     static constexpr ft zero = 0.0;
}; 

template<> class IntegrationWorkspaceTraits<float>
{
    public:
    typedef float ft; //float_type
    static constexpr ft zero = 0.0f;
};
```

And now I have a class that uses this traits that look like this

```
template< typename T, typename AT = IntegrationWorkspaceTraits<T> >    GslIntegrationWorkspace
{
    typedef typename AT::ft   ft;
    typedef typename AT::zero zero;

    public:
    GslIntegrationWorkspace(size_t size);

    private:
    typename std::vector<ft> alist;
}
```

My question is: How to use the zero constant that is defined on traits in order to set the initial value of the member vector. My guess is something like

```
template<typename T, typename AT> 
GslIntegrationWorkspace::GslIntegrationWorkspace( size_t size ):
alist(size, typename AT::zero),   
{};
```

But compiler g++ complains "gsl_integration.h:63:42: error: invalid use of template-name ‘GslIntegrationWorkspace’ without an argument list"

best

Comment: Do you really need a trait to give you back `T` and `T()`? This looks like complete overkill... `alist(size)` would have exactly the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`zero` is a value, not a type! You need this:

```
typedef typename AT::ft ft;
static constexpr ft     zero = AT::zero;
```

Now you can use `GslIntegrationWorkspace<double>::zero`, etc. In the constructor you would of course just need `alist(size, zero)`.

If you don't ODR-use the value (e.g. take its address), you won't even need to have a definition for it - the inline declaration and initialization should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on " static constexpr ft     zero = AT::zero; "

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your constructor like this:

```
template<typename T, typename AT> 
GslIntegrationWorkspace<T, AT>::GslIntegrationWorkspace( size_t size ):
    alist(size, AT::zero),   
{
}
```

Your post was also missing a `class` when defining `GslIntegrationWorkspace`.

Comment: missing class was a typo here

Comment: Thanks...the first suggestion (GslIntegrationWorkspace<T, AT>) and without typename worked!